# Javascript check if csv file is comma separated

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, import

I need to import some file and I need to check if it's a csv file and if it's comma separated.
For the first question I haven't problem, but how can I do for the second?

```js
$(document).on('change', '.selectFileImport', function(){
  var oFile = document.getElementById('selectedFile').files[0];

  if (! /^(text\/csv)$/i.test(oFile.type)) {
    alert("Strange File!!!"); 
  }else{
    alert("Is a CSV file... now how can I check if it's comma separated?"); 
  }
                        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="selectedFile" class="selectFileImport" />
```

Comment: Might want to look at using a library like papaparse.js

Comment: If you're going to upload the file, the validation should be done on the server.  Even if you do it on the client, it should also always happen on the server.  So ask yourself how critical it is to do it in both places.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using file system (fs):

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('ofile', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
   if(err) throw err;

   if(data.split(',').length > 0) {
      // it is comma separated
   } else {
      // it is NOT comma separated
   }
}
```